Neutrino oscillation via some unknown interaction mechanism
My query is based on this post. Similar to the Feynman diagram proposed in the problem, why don't we consider a similar mechanism in beyond standard model to explain the neutrino oscillation? It would put both the quark oscillation and neutrino oscillation on equal footing.

But then you need to encode the oscillation parameters into this new interaction vertex per neutrino so that you correctly get different interactions simply on how far from the source a detector is.

But... the quark oscillation amps are suppressed by at least 1/$M_W$, etc... Why do you want to weaken the "conventional" neutrino oscillation with two extra PMNS suppressions and such a propagator suppression? Have you estimated the overall relative suppression factor?
